# Predictions Incorrect For Trained Keras Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, batch-normalization

I have trained an image classifier CNN for 50 epochs and achieved 65% accuracy with 64% accuracy on the validation data.

My problem is when using `model.predict` on a single sample (one image) the network behaves as though it is untrained.

I fed model.predict thousands of images, one at a time and the average classification accuracy was only 46%.

I tried using both `model.save_model` and saving the json model and weights separately, but there was no difference.

My only thought as to why this is occurring is to do with the BatchNorm layers in my model effecting the consistency of the data.

My model contains six CNN layers, with three max pooling and one final fully connected layer, with a BatchNormalisation layer between every layer (seven in total). I used a batch size of 128 during training, but of course the batch size for the prediction samples is 1. I don't know much about BatchNorm, but I wonder if there is some kind of normalisation that is happening on the training and testing data but not on the predictions?

Comment: Do you normalized your image as in training phase? E.g. made it to have `0` mean and variance equal to `1`? Or squashed the input to `(0, 1)` interval?